# Java, strong typing, covariance and contra-variance

Tags: type-theory, java

While studying for a test in my OOP course, I came upon this question which had an answer I didn't really understand. The question is as follows (translated):

The programming language "Sava" is similar to Java in every way except in the following:

1. It's structurally typed
2. When overriding a method the argument can be contravariant and the return type can be covariant.

Given the following class and interface, is the following assignment legal?

```
  interface I{
    boolean equals(I i){…}
  } 

  class C{
    boolean equals(C c){…}
  }

I i = new C();
```

The answer that was given to this question was:
The assignment isn't legal. The equals method in C changes the paramater in a covariant way and so it doesn't match the equals method in I.

At first I thought the professor forgot to add "Implements I" but the answer also stated the following:
Answers that refereed to the fact that C doesn't implement I weren't accepted because given that it's a Structurally Typed language it doesn't matter if it were a subtype.

I'm not sure I understand how we can refer to these methods as covariant / contravariant if there is no relation of subtyping between C and I.

Can anyone clear this up for me?

Comment: Doesn't `C` _implement_ `I`?

Comment: By "structural typing" your professor assumes the relation of subtyping to be implicit.

Answer (score 2):

"Structurally typed" means that you don't need to write `implements I`: if your type has all the methods `I` has, with compatible signatures, it's automatically a subtype of `I`. However, in this case, `C.equals(C)` does *not* implement `I.equals(I)` (due to variance) and so `C` isn't a subtype of `I`.

EDIT:

> I'll explain: For C to be structurally equivalent to I we need to know the type hierarchy for the arguments of equals.

Yes, here you have recursive structural types, which complicate the issue quite a bit.

> The equals method in C changes the paramater in a covariant way and so it doesn't match the equals method in I.

This is strictly speaking incorrect, this isn't covariant (again, since `C` isn't a subtype of `I`). It should instead say e.g. "if we assume `C` is a subtype of `I`, then the equals method in `C` changes the parameter in a covariant way and we get a contradiction". You could claim `C` and `I` should be treated as *equivalent* (i.e. both subtypes of each other), and then there is no contradiction.

Another problem is that definition of `C` depends on `C` itself, so you have recursive structural types, which complicate the language quite a bit.

Comment: How can we discuss the issue of variance if there isn't a subtype relation? I'll explain:
For C to be structurally equivalent to I we need to know the type hierarchy for the arguments of equals. Since we don't know it shouldn't the answer be "The assignment isn't legal because there isn't a subtype relationship?"